# Function that creates an object to add to an array of pointers

Tags: c++, new-operator

I'm a bit confused w.r.t. the usage of `delete` and creation of new objects. Say I have a class which stores pointers to some other object in an array:

```
#include <array>
#include "someObject.hpp"
class someContainer() {
    std::array<someObject*, 10> objects;
    void set_object(int n);
}
```

What is the best way to create and store instances of `someObject` in the `set_object` function that does *not* involve the usage of smart pointers or other wrappers.

For example, I believe that...

```
void someContainer::set_object(n) {
    // Some check that 0 < n < 9
    ...
    //=====
    someObject object* = &someObject(constructor_param);
    objects[n] = object;
}
```

... will result in undefined behavior, because the destructor of `object`'s reference is called upon the function's exit.

Would the correct way, then, be this?

```
void someContainer::set_object(n) {
    // Some check that 0 < n < 9
    ...
    //=====
    someObject object* = new someObject(constructor_param);
    objects[n] = object;
}

void someContainer::~someContainer() {
    int len = objects.size
    for (int i=0; i < len; i++) {
        delete objects[i];
    }
```

Or is there undefined behavior somewhere that I'm missing? (Also, I think that one shouldn't iterate through the array while also deleting objects from it, which is why I use the `len` index. Is this true?) I'm asking here because things compile and *seem* to work well, but I'm having a hard time really knowing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an important issue in memory management: who owns an allocated value, i. e. who is responsible for freeing it. If you call

```
object[n] = new someObject(constructor_param);
```

and there is already an object stored there, the old object will remain somewhere on the heap, maybe without any pointers left to it, so it can't ever be freed again.

You would probably want your setter to look like this:

```cpp
someObject *someContainer::set_object(n) {
    // Some check that 0 < n < 9
    ...
    //=====
    someObject *previous = objects[n];
    objects[n] = new someObject(constructor_param);
    return previous;
}
```

to signal to the user of the function that he needs to deal with the previous object, either `delete` it immediately or store it somewhere.

Also, you are completely free to `delete` the objects in a regular loop: remember that you are only freeing the objects that the array elements point to, and are not changing the array at all.

Comment: `return previous;` - that is a good way to leak memory, unless you mark the function as `[[nodiscard]]` (C++17 and later only). Otherwise, you should return a `std::unique_ptr<someObject>` instead. Or, just don't `return` anything at all, just `delete` the previous object before exit.  This is where making the array be `std::array<std::unique_ptr<someObject>, 10>` instead comes in handy.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Why unnecessarily restrict it to a `unique_ptr`? When using the GSL, one could annotate the return type as `owner<someObject*>` for clarity.

Comment: @Tau the point is, if you are going to return the previous object, it must be made clear that the caller is expected to take ownership of it, and that ownership should be automatic in case the caller chooses to ignore it. `unique_ptr` provides that guarantee. `gsl::owner` is just an anotation, it doesn't actually affect anything in code, and it certainly does not enforce automatic ownership.

Comment: Of course, `unique_ptr` is safest in the specific case, but as the question does not state whether the container is supposed to own its contents or not, this is the best one can do in the general case.